# "OAuth request must be over HTTPS" when request is over https

Tags: bug, status-completed, oauth2

I had a bug reported to me that I was able to reproduce.  When authorizing to my [Badges webapp](https://stackapps.com/questions/2982/stinkingbadges-track-your-progress-towards-long-term-badges?noredirect=1#comment10646_2982), we get the following error:

> error: invalid_request
>   error description: OAuth request must be over HTTPS

However, I checked and the request URL is:

`https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=74&redirect_uri=http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge/`

...which appears to be using https:// as required.

I haven't touched the app in months, so unless something has changed and I'm oblivious, I'm not sure how it could be my bug.  Could someone take a look and give some guidance?

Comment: Even the API documentation fails with the same error, so it must be an internal problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We moved from nginx to HAProxy for our SSL provider this weekend as part of a larger rollout.  In the move, we shifted our header checks to the now de-facto standard SSL protocol header.  While I *thought* I fixed all the apps relying on the old header and standardized everything internally, stackexchange.com was left out and thought your auth requests weren't over SSL anymore.

I just deployed a se.com build that resolves this, requests should now be working correctly.